# Inverting Schmitt Trigger

Tags: operational-amplifier

I do not understand the role of \$R_1\$ in the inverting Schmitt trigger design as seen below. Why can it not be removed?

[image]

Comment: who says it can't?

Comment: @JonRB it was a given answer, I assume it is there for a reason, not sure which reason

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the comparator has a totem-pole output (drives both high and low active) the circuit will work just fine without R1 - as long as you're willing to switch at Vref.

R1 is used simply for convenience. Without it, the nominal trip point (ignoring hysteresis introduced by R3) is fixed at Vref. Adding R1 allows adjustment of the trip point to any value between Vref and ground, although the amount of hysteresis changes for a fixed R3 as the Thevenin equivalent resistance of R1/R2 varies.